# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 - Ajax doesn't work in <a> element

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use Ajax in ASP.NET 5. With form it successfully works but with hyperlink element doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
<a asp-controller="Playlist" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"
   data-ajax="true" data-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#AllPlaylistsDiv">
      Delete
</a>
```

It doesn't call the controller.
What could I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code that is sent to the browser?

Comment: I run the program with the "web" command, so it opens a console. When I click on it, the result (in the console) is 404. [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B60EADC41A6D8F77!308664&authkey=!ACEaZ6DU8c0Et1Q&ithint=file%2ctxt). Unfortunately I don't really understand the message.

Comment: Here is the controller code [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B60EADC41A6D8F77!308665&authkey=!AIGw5-7E7dZKczs&ithint=file%2ctxt).

Comment: Ups. Here is the code that is sent to the browser: "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR): GET - http://localhost:5000/Playlist/Delete/2ab2bbf4-4509-4ea0-b645-c064e09ea9b4?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1458502739461"

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the problem!
Instead of data-method I've wrote data-ajax-method.
Everything is working.